# Redirect user to root after trying to access a page without being authenticated to do so in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so, as the title says, how can I redirect the user to the root instead of the sign_in page after the user attempts to access a protected page?

This is my routes.rb file

```
.
.
. 
  root 'pages#home'

  authenticate :user do
     mount Kibana::Sinatra::Web => '/kibana', :trailing_slash => true
  end
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using authenticate_user! in your controller do the following:

In Your Application Controller add this:

```
  protected
  def authenticate_user!
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "You are not authorised to access this page" unless user_signed_in?
  end
```

but if you want to authenticate from routes you have to use constraints

1. Edit your routes to look as following and match not found urls to root:

   ```
   mount Kibana::Sinatra::Web => '/kibana', :trailing_slash => true, :constraints => AllowAccess.new
   match ':not_found' => redirect('/'), :constraints => { :not_found => /.*/ }
   ```
2. Create a new constraint "allow_access" in your lib folder and the following code

   ```
   class AllowAccess
     def matches?(request)
       return false unless request.session["warden.user.user.key"]
     end
   end
   ```

And add this line in your application.rb to autoload the lib file

```
   config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: Thank you. But this didn't work for me, im still redirected to /user/sign_in instead of root.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the update. Could you be a little more detailed about where I should create the allow_access.rb file? The lib in the project directory of the lib of the devise gem directory? Thank you.

Comment: In your rails lib directory , and don't forget to restart your server

Comment: That raised the following error when starting the server: uninitialized constant AllowAccess (NameError)

Comment: Updated answer with lib autoload